# Interface Jython script from Python3 module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jython

If I have a script, or in this case just a function or two, written in Jython -- is there a way to interact with that code from my Python3 project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not until Jython catches up with CPython enough for your whole Python 3 project to run in Jython. You can't run part of a Python application with one interpreter and the rest with another. You might be able to juggle multiple processes using remote procedure calls using pickle, but it'll be complex and brittle, not to mention slow (has to copy all data involved). If it's pure Python, just port those two functions to Python 3 ([likely easy](http://python3porting.com/)), or port your project to Python 2.5 (probably much harder). If it uses Jython's JVM interop, there are alternatives working with CPython, though possibly less mature. Depending on what you need Java for, there might be a pure Python alternative.

Comment: In this case I wanted to use Sikuli to automate a portion of the workflow. Seeing as its written in Jython, and its output scripts are in Jython, I was hoping I could call them from my main project; which is written in Python3.

Comment: The question is whether it has to run in the same process. If you can run the scripts from the command line, you can do that from Python 3 too.